# Synchronous DB access using Node.js and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I want to perform a find query to MongoDB to check whether a particular entry is in DB or not. But it calls a callback function which is asynchronous. How can I get the result?

In this I am not getting the actual result synchronously.

Comment: Can you post the sample code ? Are you directly using the node.js MongoDB driver ? or you are using anything like Mongoose ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Node.js you ought to do it the asynchronous way.

Example:

```
db_call(query, function (err, result) {
  if (err) { throw new Error('db_error'); return; }
  console.log(result); // do your stuff here
});
```

Comment: I am using the same way like:                                function authenticateUser(msg) {
var result = true;
db.open(function (error, client) {
  if (error) throw error;
  var collection = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'users');
  collection.find({'key':msg}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    log.info(docs.length);
 if(docs.length != 1)
 result = false;
  });
});
return result;
} In this case I am not getting result value when I call this authenticate method.As we do not know when callback will be fired.

Comment: right place to post your code would be in the original question and not in comment section. If there is a lot of code you can use https://gist.github.com/.